# How to check for the presence of attribute wrapped in "mut" helper?

Tags: ember.js

Writing a component in Ember 2.0, if a user can decide whether to wrap an attribute in "mut" helper or not. What is the best way to check for the presence of a wrapper?

I see in console that a wrapped object looks like:

```
Object {value: Array[100], MUTABLE_CELL [id=__ember1439432660745930580273638]: true}
```

Is the key `MUTABLE_CELL [id=__ember1439432660745930580273638]` somewhere so I could `import` it and check against it?

Answer (score 0):

With some good luck and hacking, I have found the following function does the trick:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
var getMutValue = Ember.__loader.require('ember-htmlbars/hooks/get-value')['default'];

... 
obj = this.attrs[key];
val = getMutValue(obj);
// val is obj if obj is not a mut; is obj.value otherwise.
```

I will accept another answer if someone could indicate how to do this via the Ember public API.